# Arduino Nano ESP32 digitalread() frequency

Tags: arduino-nano, digital

for a project I'm trying to read an digital sensor signal with an Arduino Nano ESP32. I read on a different forum that the digitalread() function lasts 79 ticks, so with a clock speed of 16MHz this would result in a read frequency of 200KHz. My question is now, if i use the ESP32 which runs at 240MHz would this mean that the read frequency is around 3MHz?

edit:
time_per_tick = 1/clock_speed
read_freq = 1/(79 * time_per_tick)

Comment: You can't use measurements for completely different MCU. On AVRs there is lot of extra steps because of PROGMEM and those aren't needed on ARM architecture.